# Android Studio hangs when creating new Google Cloud Module

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

OS : Mac OS X version 10.9.5

Android Studio : (version 1.3, build#: AI-141.2017176)

Reference : https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/endpoints/add_module

When creating a new Google Cloud Module, Android Studio hangs up and doesn't allow to do anything. Also cannot see any background process running. I waited for about an hour but I don't see any progress.

I tried updating android studio, restarting machine, but it does not work. Any help is appreciated.

[update]

I tried with the old version of android studio, and it worked. Then I tried with the version 1.3, build#: AI-141.2017176, and I get the same problem.

It looks like the latest canary build has some issues

Comment: This happens for me too on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Fixed for me in Beta 1 update today.